# Simple vs cryptic usernames

Tags: linux, security, passwords

When creating users (for instance in a linux system), are there any security recommendations for the syntax of the username?

Let´s say:
Is "FTP_User1" less "secure" than something like "Xg_32_FTP_User1_043"?

I have already seen this attempt of trying to bloat usernames several times but never came to a conclusion whether it is actually helpful. It might prevent attackers from guessing account names, but that won´t help them a lot when a strong password is used.

Any thoughts?

Comment: IMO it's more annoying than helpful.

Comment: (perceived) Security by Obscurity, nothing else.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @zaph I'd say you gain most if your not using publicly available "username is-a email address" that can easily be obtained and validated before performing an actual attack. Your answer reflects much of Jeff's point in [Password Rules Are BS](https://blog.codinghorror.com/password-rules-are-bullshit/) applied to usernames: Don't allow those that are already known to be insecure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that cryptic usernames are very useful in terms of security, because they are often visible anyhow. For example:

- Linux has commands like `users` to print the user names of users
  currently logged in to the current host
- in `${HOME}` you can see all users' home directories in the form `${HOME}/FTP_User1/` (although you may not have permissions to access them)
- usernames may appear as owner of files or folders, in logfiles and in various other places

Cryptic usernames are only "security through obscurity", but not "real security". If you want a secure Linux system, you'll need to carefully set access permissions and encourage good passwords.

Answer (score 0):

No, there aren't such recommendations and there really shouldn't be.

Usernames aren't a secret, and the word "secret" has a rather specific meaning in information security - it is something that you must keep hidden at all costs (i.e. passwords, encryption keys, etc).

It is common sense to make life harder for potential attackers, but attempting to make usernames unguessable may only stop the teenage hacker wannabes, who wouldn't be able to go past the next step (e.g. password protection) anyway.
Any skilled attacker wouldn't even try to guess, but would find a direct way to get a full list of your usernames, or have a go at one they already know exists.

It is *leaking* usernames via other means that you must prevent. Making the login names unguessable is just a waste of time, and **really** annoying to users.